# "For + him/her/them + was + to+infinitive" vs " was + for him/her/them to + infinitive"

Tags: infinitives, prepositional-phrases

The following sentence is from a book. [1]

> Her dying wish was for him to hike the Ap. trail.

Why didn't the author write it as:

> Her dying wish for him was to hike the Ap. trail.

Is there any difference between the two sentences above?

---

[1] D.Miller AWOL on the AT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Her dying wish was for him to hike the Ap. trail.

Him hiking the Ap. trail was her entire dying wish. Her dying wish equaled him taking up the hike.

> Her dying wish for him was to hike the Ap. trail.

She may have had many dying wishes for different people. The one she had for him was him doing the hike.